# Can not redeclare class Requests

Tags: php, autoload

I am working on kind of a lib which is using `Requests` library. I am getting error given in title. I am doing following:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
        include 'vendor/rmccue/requests/library/Requests.php';
        $class_file = $class_name.'.php';
        print $class_file;
        if(file_exists($class_file)) {
            include $class_file;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Unable to load $class_name.<br>.<br>.<br>");
        }
    }
$session = new Session($instanceID,$profileID,$routerID,$api_endpoint,$headers);
   $session->createSession();
```

Since `Requests` will be used in multiple classes, I want to load up once. How can I do it?

**Session.php**

```
class Session
{
    private $instanceID = null;
    private $profileID = null;
    private $routerID = null;
    private $apiEndpoint = null;
    private $headers = null;

    public function __construct($instance_id,$profile_id,$router_id,$api_endpoint,$headers)
    {
        $this->instanceID = $instance_id;
        $this->profileID = $profile_id;
        $this->routerID = $router_id;
        $this->apiEndpoint = $api_endpoint;
        $this->headers = $headers;
    }

    public function createSession()
    {
        $create_session_url = $this->apiEndpoint.'createSession?{"accountID":"39BB2F17-89D6-2093-B133-76C21D513EDF"}';
        $create_session_url = 'https://api.xx.cc/api/index.php/smartcall/createSession?{%22accountID%22:%2239BB2F17-89D6-2093-B133-76C21D513EDF%22}';
        $request = \Requests::get($create_session_url, $this->headers);
        var_dump($request->body);
    }

}
```

**Update #1**
By Doing this now I am said: *Class Session not found*:

```
include 'vendor/rmccue/requests/library/Requests.php';
    \Requests::register_autoloader();

    function __autoload($class_name) {

        $class_file = $class_name.'.php';
        if ($class_file != 'Requests.php') {
            print $class_file;
            if(file_exists($class_file)) {
                include_once $class_file;
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Unable to load $class_name.<br>.<br>.<br>");
            }
        }

    }

$session = new Session($instanceID,$profileID,$routerID,$api_endpoint,$headers);
    $session->createSession();
```

Comment: The error happens becuase `Request.php` is already included or required somewhere else, check your previously included files

Comment: No it's not anywhere else, there's no redeclaration of Request class and the code I gave here is the only calling class

Comment: This is what the error is saying

Comment: Inwhat line exactly is the error thrown? I see _two_ include statements here, whyever.

Comment: @arkascha it's being thrown on line 21 of Request library

Comment: Which is included by which of the two include statements? The first or the second?

Comment: @arkascha Question updated further

Answer (score 1):

Use `include_once` instead of `include`.

> `include_once` may be used in cases where the same file might be included and evaluated more than once during a particular execution of a script, so in this case it may help avoid problems such as function redefinitions, variable value reassignments, etc.

See the docs here: [include_once()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)

Answer (score 0):

Every time a class is auto-included, you try to include your library:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include 'vendor/rmccue/requests/library/Requests.php';
```

Using `include_once` would probably solve that but in reality the auto-loader should be configured to load `Request` automatically as well when it is needed.

So you should really not include the library in your auto-load function, have your auto-load function handle *all* classes.

Comment: So I should not `autoload` and check whether the file is not `Request.php`, if yes then load else ignore?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so `spl_autoload_register` was the answer. The issue was arising because my code had an `__autolod` and `spl_autoload_register`(within library).

From the [manual](http://php.net/spl_autoload_register):

> If your code has an existing __autoload() function then this function
>   must be explicitly registered on the __autoload queue. This is because
>   spl_autoload_register() will effectively replace the engine cache for
>   the __autoload() function by either spl_autoload() or
>   spl_autoload_call().

I did following changes in **call.php**:

```
include_once 'vendor/rmccue/requests/library/Requests.php';
\Requests::register_autoloader();
```

and changed `__autoload()` to simple function name, eg: `autoload` and called it in `spl_autoload_register()`. Code given below:

```
function autoload($class_name) {

        $class_file = $class_name.'.php';
        if ($class_file != 'Requests.php')
        {
            if(file_exists($class_file)) {
                include_once $class_file;
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Unable to load $class_name.<br>.<br>.<br>");
            }
        }

    }
    spl_autoload_register('autoload');
```

Since all classes are being queued via `spl_autoload_register` hence there's no conflict. I can just call `Request` once and the can use my own classes.